# Playing with packages in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, python-import

I am working with a Python package that uses relative imports. So from one module, local imports look like:

```
from . import module
```

The package is structured like so:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  module2.py
  moduleN.py
  subpackage1/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
  subpackage2/
    __init__.py
    ...
  etc.
```

I would like to import one of these modules to try out its functions and classes in isolation.

So, I `cd`ed into the `package/` directory. Then I tried `ipython module2.py` and got:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I also tried `ipython -m module2` and in addition to `ValueError`, I also got:

```
WARNING: Unknown failure executing module: <module2>
```

I also tried the same thing from one directory up and got the same errors.

How can I import the modules and use their classes and functions inside of  IPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `ipython` from inside of the top-level directory of the project, in this case, `package/`.

Then import the modules with absolute imports:

```
import package.module2 as module2
```

or

```
import package.submodule1.module1 as m1
```